Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip'
I opened a new project on Android Studio and I got an error stating
Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip'.
Reason: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
I ensured my connection wasnt a problem then I tried to manually download the zip file from the url provided (https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip) I expected the download to begin but I got a timeout error on my browser as well
I also tried the "invalidate cache" fix from the menu and still got the same result
has anyone experienced this issue in April 2024 and How did I go about it?
